# Generate ASP.NET webpages_membership Password using nodejs

Tags: c#, php, node.js

There is existing system is working on C#, but we have decided to move some modules of c# website into nodejs, so i will be able to login through c# and nodejs too. using c# registration it generated some random password using some existing library of asp.net it will store password into **"webpages_membership"** table.

**C# generated random password :** "JWvppSSfnzOQ+uMd+BORpT/8aQorC8y05Bjbo/8w/9b/eiG4WLzUFRQSSiKZqo3C" is hashed password for "123456" string.

so now there is some other module which will be now in nodejs but rest of the things will be in c# only. so login now i have to login through node.

I am trying to compare c# generated password in nodejs using following 
library 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aspnet-identity-pw

but it returns False.

c# generated password for "123456" => "JWvppSSfnzOQ+uMd+BORpT/8aQorC8y05Bjbo/8w/9b/eiG4WLzUFRQSSiKZqo3C"

Please help me to achieve same in nodejs.

**nodejscode**

```
var passwordHasher = require('aspnet-identity-pw');

var hashedPassword = passwordHasher.hashPassword('123456');
console.log(hashedPassword);

var isValid = passwordHasher.validatePassword('JWvppSSfnzOQ+uMd+BORpT/8aQorC8y05Bjbo/8w/9b/eiG4WLzUFRQSSiKZqo3C', hashedPassword);
console.log("Result:"+isValid);
//Return False
```

I tried same thing in php using below code which is working fine, using below php code i am able to compare c# generated password and also able to generate new password from php and able to login from C#.

**Working PHPcode for reference:**

```
<?php

/*
 * Author  : Mr. Juned Ansari
 * Date    : 15/02/2017 
 * Purpose : It Handles Login Encryption And Decryption Related Activities
 */

class MembershipModel {

    function bytearraysequal($source, $target) {
        if ($source == null || $target == null || (strlen($source) != strlen($target)))
            return false;
        for ($ctr = 0; $ctr < strlen($target); $ctr++) {
            if ($target[$ctr] != $source[$ctr])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    //This Function is Used to verifypassword
    function verifypassword($hashedPassword, $password) {

        $PBKDF2IterCount = 1000; // default for Rfc2898DeriveBytes
        $PBKDF2SubkeyLength = 32; // 256 bits       
        $SaltSize = 16; // 128 bits


        if ($hashedPassword == null) {
            return false;
            //show_error("hashedPassword is null");
        }
        if ($password == null) {
            return false;
            //show_error("Password is null");
        }

        $hashedPasswordBytes = base64_decode($hashedPassword);

        if (strlen($hashedPasswordBytes) != 48) {
            return false;
        }

        $salt = substr($hashedPasswordBytes, 0, $SaltSize);

        $storedSubkey = substr($hashedPasswordBytes, $SaltSize, $PBKDF2SubkeyLength);

        $generatedSubkey = $this->encript('sha1', $password, $salt, $PBKDF2IterCount, $PBKDF2SubkeyLength, true);

        return $this->bytearraysequal($storedSubkey, $generatedSubkey);
    }

    function encript($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false) {
        $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
        if (!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
            return false;
        //show_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.');
        if ($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
            return false;
        //show_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.');

        $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
        $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

        $output = "";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {

            $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);

            $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);

            for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
                $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
            }
            $output .= $xorsum;
        }
        return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
    }

}
---------------------------------
echo MembershipModel::verifypassword("JWvppSSfnzOQ+uMd+BORpT/8aQorC8y05Bjbo/8w/9b/eiG4WLzUFRQSSiKZqo3C","123456");
//Returns True for every c# generated password

$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$dev = MembershipModel::encript('sha1', $Password, $salt, 1000, 32, true);
$HashedPassword = base64_encode($salt.$dev);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can port your working  PHP code to Node.js using the built-in [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module.

***Creating a hash:***

In your PHP `MembershipModel::encript` method you're using a PBKDF2 implementation to create a key. We can create the same key in Node.js with [`crypto.pbkdf2Sync`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2sync_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest).

```
function kdf(password, salt, count=1000, keyLen=32, hash='sha1') {
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, count, keyLen, hash);
}
```

Now we can write a function that uses `kdf` and returns the salt and key, base64 encoded - the same format as your PHP and C# code.

```
function hashPassword(password) {
    var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    var key = kdf(password, salt, 1000, 32, 'sha1');
    var sk = Buffer.concat([salt, key]);
    return sk.toString('base64');
}
```

For the salt I've used [`crypto.randomBytes`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) which is a CSPRNG function (creates secure pseudo-random data).

***Checking a hash:***

In your PHP `MembershipModel::verifypassword` method you're using the received salt to craete a key with PBKDF2, then compare the new key with the received key. A Node.js equivalent:

```
function verifyPassword(hashedPassword, password) {
    var data = new Buffer(hashedPassword, 'base64');
    var salt = data.slice(0, 16);
    var key = data.slice(16);
    var hash = kdf(password, salt);
    return crypto.timingSafeEqual(key, hash);
}
```

I'm using [`crypto.timingSafeEqual`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_timingsafeequal_a_b) to compare the keys; it performs constant time comparison.

***Testing:***

```
var password = "123456";
var hash = hashPassword(password);
console.log(hash);
//umzeh4aAeD1Ee6z4oN/BS9f2s2GQ7gswtbrguEr2C32c8XK99UjI8LkgYapbX8/N
console.log(verifyPassword(hash, password));
//true

hash = "JWvppSSfnzOQ+uMd+BORpT/8aQorC8y05Bjbo/8w/9b/eiG4WLzUFRQSSiKZqo3C";
console.log(verifyPassword(hash, password));
//true
```

We can see that the `hashPassword` function produces hashes that are compatible with your PHP code and `verifyPassword` can verify them successfully.

---

Some notes about your PHP code:

I assume that the `MembershipModel::bytearraysequal` method is supposed to use a constant time algorithm, but it returns false with the first occurrence of unequal characters. A better implementation, using bitwise operators:

```
function bytearraysEqual(string $hash1, string $hash2): bool {
    $result = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($hash1) && $i<strlen($hash2); $i++) {
        $result |= ord($hash1[$i]) ^ ord($hash2[$i]);
    }
    return $result === 0 && strlen($hash1) === strlen($hash2);
}
```

This function checks all the characters, and the length of strings. However, it's best to use the built-in [`hash_equals`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) function (requires PHP 5.6 or higher). Similarly, you can use [`openssl_pbkdf2`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pbkdf2.php) to create the key (PHP 5.5 or higher).

We can improve your `MembershipModel` class using those functions, and type hinting (PHP 7) which doesn't require null checks, and produces cleaner code.

```
class MembershipModel {

    const PBKDF2_ALGORITHM = "SHA1"; 
    const PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 1000; 
    const KEY_LENGTH = 32;    
    const SALT_LENGTH = 16;

    function hashPassword(string $password): string {
        $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        $key = MembershipModel::kdf($password, $salt);
        return base64_encode($salt.$key);
    }

    function verifyPassword(string $hashedPassword, string $password): bool {
        $hashedPasswordBytes = base64_decode($hashedPassword);
        $salt = substr($hashedPasswordBytes, 0, MembershipModel::SALT_LENGTH);
        $key1 = substr($hashedPasswordBytes, MembershipModel::SALT_LENGTH);
        $key2 = MembershipModel::kdf($password, $salt);
        return hash_equals($key1, $key2);
    }

    private function kdf(string $password, string $salt): string {
        $key = hash_pbkdf2(
            MembershipModel::PBKDF2_ALGORITHM, $password, $salt, 
            MembershipModel::PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, MembershipModel::KEY_LENGTH,
            true
        );
        return $key;
    }
}
```

---

Your key derivation scheme seems secure enough: PBKDF2 with a random salt and long key. You could increase the number of iterations for better security, but that would cost time and performance.

The implementation however may have bugs (like the one I found in `MembershipModel::bytearraysequal`) that could reduce the security of your code. It's best to use built-in functions, if that is possible.

---

***Update***

After studying the source code of `aspnet-identity-pw`, I discovered that it uses `crypto` internally. The key is created by  `crypto.pbkdf2` with 16 byte salt and 1000 iterations. The only difference is that it creates a 49 byte hash, with a zero byte at the front.

The hash format is `0 + salt[16] + key[32]`, so could use this hash if we slice off the first byte. For example:

```
const passwordHasher = require('aspnet-identity-pw');

function hashPassword(password) {
    var hash = passwordHasher.hashPassword(password);
    var bytes = Buffer(hash, 'base64');
    return bytes.slice(1).toString('base64');
}

function verifyPassword(hashedPassword, password) {
    var bytes = new Buffer(hashedPassword, 'base64');
    var hash = Buffer.concat([new Buffer([0x00]), bytes]).toString('base64');
    return passwordHasher.validatePassword(password, hash);
}

var hash = "JWvppSSfnzOQ+uMd+BORpT/8aQorC8y05Bjbo/8w/9b/eiG4WLzUFRQSSiKZqo3C";
console.log(verifyPassword(hash, '123456'))
//true
```

This code also produces results that are compatible with your PHP code. Personally, I would rather use `crypto` directly because it is more flexible, and also `aspnet-identity-pw` [doesn't use a constant time algorithm](https://github.com/Syncbak-Git/aspnet-identity-pw/blob/master/lib/aspnet-identity-pw.js#L137) when comparing hashes. But I understand that `aspnet-identity-pw` may be easier to use, and it may be safer for less experienced users.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you should send in the password as the first parameter in validatePassword. So try this:

```js
var passwordHasher = require('aspnet-identity-pw');

var hashedPassword = passwordHasher.hashPassword('123456');
console.log(hashedPassword);

var isValid = passwordHasher.validatePassword('123456', hashedPassword);
console.log("Result:"+isValid);
```

Comment: hashedPassword will be c# generated password using webpage_membership module which generated some random password like "JWvppSSfnzOQ+uMd+BORpT/8aQorC8y05Bjbo/8w/9b/eiG4WLzUFRQSSiKZqo3C"